# Undefined reference to member function (C++)

Tags: c++, object, initialization, undefined-reference

I am using a Makefile to compile a C++ project, and I receive an undefined reference error which I suspect is for a simple mistake.

The error itself is:

```
$ make
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ -o p5 main.o
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x241): undefined reference to `Instructions::processInput(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:2: recipe for target `p5' failed
make: *** [p5] Error 1
```

Here are the parts of the project concerned with the error (for clarity's sake):
My makefile:

```
p5: main.o Instructions.o
    g++ -o p5 main.o

main.o: main.cpp Instructions.h
    g++ -c main.cpp

Instructions.o: Instructions.h Instructions.cpp
    g++ -c Instructions.cpp
```

My main.cpp file:

```
#include <string>
#include "Instructions.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Instructions inst;
    inst.processInput("some string par example"); //THIS LINE HERE GIVES ME ERRORS
    return 0;
}
```

My Instructions header file:

```
#ifndef INSTRUCTIONS_H
#define INSTRUCTIONS_H
#include <string>

class Instructions {
public:
    Instructions() {input = ""; command = 0; xCoord = 0.0; yCoord = 0.0;};
    void processInput(std::string in);
private:
    std::string input;
    int command;
    double xCoord;
    double yCoord;
};
#endif
```

And finally the .cpp file, very barebones at the moment:

```
#include "Instructions.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Instructions::processInput(string in) {
    cout << "Processing: " << input << endl;
}
```

I've been looking around for solutions but to no avail. Please excuse me then if it is indeed somewhere else! I also hope it helps all the beginners out there still coming to terms with C++!

Comment: maybe it thinks that "some string par example" means a char* instead of a string, so what you are really calling is processInput(char*) instead of processInput(string). In this case, try doing processInput(string("helloimastring"))

Comment: Hey, @ForgiveMeI'mAN00b, I tried that and while it should compile, it gives me the same error. I assume this is because while corrrect syntax, the problem is the same.

Comment: odd, sorry though that's the best help i can do, I don't quite grasp all the stuff to do with compilation yet myself... :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this please Makefile :

```
 p5: Instructions.o main.o
     g++ Instructions.o main.o -o p5 

 Instructions.o: Instructions.cpp
     g++ -c Instructions.cpp -o Instructions.o 

 main.o: main.cpp Instructions.h
     g++ -c main.cpp Instructions.o -o main.o
```

to compile `p5`, you need first to compile all its dependencies which is `Instructions.o` and `main.o`. `Instructions.o` is independent, so it can be compiled like this `g++ -c Instructions.cpp`. But `main.o` depend on the class *Instructions* so it depend on its `.o` It should be compiled like this `g++ -c main.cpp Instructions.o`.

Same thing for `p5`, it needs all the `*.o`.

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately this doesn't work either, but it raises a doubts on my knowledge of makefiles. Does then, the .o file have to be fed instead of the .header one when making a new .o one?

Comment: how about this ? I added `Instructions.o` to the end ...check plz

Comment: Hmmm, it throws the same compiler error. Thanks for the help though, I appreciate it!

Comment: I modified the makefile, plz check if the error msg changed ?

Comment: Hey, that seems to have worked! What does this mean? The compiler needs a specific order of file making? Main files towards the end?

Comment: okey, first I need you to check my answer as Right and I will edit it right now :)